# Melhor dimensão para colocar no background app Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Desenvolvi um splash para um app android e incluí uma imagem de fundo através do comando:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg16"
```

A imagem apareceu, porém devido as dimensões dela, ela acabou ficando um pouco achatada. Existe alguma dimensão padrão para as imagens em aplicativos Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você precisa de um [Nine-Patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). É basicamente um arquivo PNG  no qual você especifica regiões bidimensionais que podem ser esticadas:

[image: Examplo de uma imagem NinePatch utilizada em um botão]

Extraído da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) sobre o suporte à telas de diferentes tamanhos:

> If your UI uses bitmaps that need to fit the size of a view even after the system scales the layout (such as the background image for a button), you should use [Nine-Patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) bitmap files. A Nine-Patch file is basically a PNG file in which you specify two-dimensional regions that are stretchable. When the system needs to scale the view in which the bitmap is used, the system stretches the Nine-Patch bitmap, but stretches only the specified regions.

---

Nine-Patches podem ser criados com o [Draw 9-patch tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) incluído no Android Studio.

Comment: Obrigado Cassio pelos esclarecimentos. Estarei acessando o link que você me passou.